# Using CSS / JS files outside of Tridion in DXA

Tags: dxa

I would like to deploy my CSS and JS files outside of Tridion using a CI process or file copy, and not store the CSS or JS files in Tridion itself.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` file I see the CSS and JS files referenced.  Is this all I need to change to reference the CSS located outside of Tridion?  And, any tips or suggestions for doing it this way?

> C:\dev\dxa-example-site-dotnet-master\dxa-example-site-dotnet-master\Site\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.VersionedContent("/assets/css/main.css")">
<script src="@Url.VersionedContent("/assets/scripts/header.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `@Url.VersionedContent` and put regular href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/main.css">
```

Comment: You don't even need to remove the `@Url.VersionedContent` as long as you make sure there is no HTML design published and you deploy a `version.json` file to the `/system/assets` folder of your Web application, which contains the version number which is added to the URLs for static assets.

Answer (score 1):

The [`_Layout.cshtml`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Site/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) file is indeed the equivalent of a master page, which takes care of defining the basic HTML page being served, which includes the links to your stylesheet. But you shouldn't even need to make any changes in there, as long as you make sure your own CSS is called `main.css` (if you want to use a fifferent file name, or even multiple, then you can of course also do that and modifly the `_Layout.cshtml` accordingly).

As I described in my blog post about [DXA HTML design decisions](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-html-design-decisions), you can simply follow the following four steps to use an "external" HTML design:

1. delete the Publish HTML Design Page (you can also delete the Component on it and its references, but simply unpublishing and deleting this page, makes the HTML design unavailable from the Broker database).
2. deploy a `version.json` file to the `/system/assets` folder of your Web application, which contains the version number which is added to the URLs for static assets, i.e.: `{"version":"v0.1"}`
3. deploy your CSS, fonts and JavaScript files to the to the `/system/assets` folder (as part of the deploy of the web application with its views)
4. update the views in case you need the HTML to be non Bootstrap

Step #1 is optional (you can leave it behind as long as you make sure it is not published), but step #2 is mandatory!

This will give you an HTML design which you deploy as part of the web application, while still being able to utilize the browser/client side caching control of the static assets through the `version.json` file.